# Generating String from List in Erlang

Tags: string, list, erlang

I'm trying to generate a formatted string based on a list:

```
[{"Max", 18}, {"Peter", 25}]
```

To a string:

```
"(Name: Max, Age: 18), (Name: Peter, Age: 35)"
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first step is to make a function that can convert your {Name, Age} tuple to a list:

```
format_person({Name, Age}) ->
    lists:flatten(io_lib:format("(Name: ~s, Age: ~b)", [Name, Age])).
```

The next part is simply to apply this function to each element in the list, and then join it together.

```
format_people(People) ->
    string:join(lists:map(fun format_person/1, People), ", ").
```

The reason for the flatten is that io_lib returns an iolist and not a flat list.

Comment: You're on fire dude... just read your sha response and it was solid too...  :)

Comment: Or you can shorten this into a one-liner under two assumptions: `string:join([ io_lib:format("(Name: ~s, Age: ~b)", [Name,Age]) || {Name,Age} <- People ], ", ")` The assumptions are that a) `string:join/2` works on `io_lib:format/2` output which it does in my tests, and that b) your output functions can handle the resulting the unflattened nested lists of characters as strings (which they really should).

Comment: Oh yes, of course, there are shorter ways. My intention was to show a straightforward implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A simple but slow way:

```
string:join([lists:flatten(io_lib:format("(~s: ~p)", [Key, Value])) || {Key,Value} <- [{"Max", 18}, {"Peter", 25}]], ", ").
```

Comment: Why do you think this is slow?

Comment: @Peer Stritzinger: Because all of `string:join/2`, `lists:flatten/1` and `io_lib:format/2` are not considered too much effective.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is important, you can use this solution:

```
format([]) -> [];
format(List) ->
  [[_|F]|R] = [ [", ","(Name: ",Name,", Age: ",integer_to_list(Age)|")"]
              || {Name, Age} <- List ],
  [F|R].
```

But remember that it returns io_list() so if you want see result, use `lists:flatten/1`. It is way how to write very efficient string manipulations in Erlang but use it only if performance is far more important than readability and maintainability.

Answer (score -1):

is it JSON?

use some already written modules in e.g mochiweb.